# How does Excel VSTO Work?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, clr-hosting

How does Excel VSTO Work?  If I create an Excel Workbook solution in Visual Studio 2005 I can then happily code away with full access to the Excel object model and even treat the Excel sheet as a design surface.  When I build the solution I get a `.XLS` file and a `.DLL` (containing my C# code).

I can now start up the Excel sheet just by double clicking on the `.XLS` and there is my sheet functioning with all my C# code and any controls I dropped on the sheet etc.

How is the sheet referencing the `.DLL`?  What part of the excel workbook/sheet tells it that it needs to fire up the CLR and host my assembly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcfbd2sk.aspx) (thanks PintSizedCat) for Excel 2003 the following happens:

> The Microsoft Office application
>   checks the custom document properties
>   to see whether there are managed code
>   extensions associated with the
>   document. For more information, see
>   Custom Document Properties Overview.
>
> If there are managed code extensions,
>   the application loads AddinLoader.dll.
>   This is an unmanaged DLL that is the
>   loader component for the Visual Studio
>   2005 Tools for Office Second Edition
>   runtime. For more information, see
>   Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime
>   Overview.
>
> AddinLoader.dll loads the .NET
>   Framework and starts the managed
>   portion of the Visual Studio Tools for
>   Office runtime.
>
> The Visual Studio Tools for Office
>   runtime creates an application domain,
>   sets policy for the application domain
>   not to trust the My Computer Zone, and
>   checks the code access security policy
>   store to find a policy for the
>   customization assembly.
>
> The .NET Framework validates the
>   evidence presented by the assembly
>   against the policy. If it fails, an
>   error is raised. If it passes, the
>   process continues.
>
> If the customization uses a deployment
>   manifest, the Visual Studio Tools for
>   Office runtime uses it to check for
>   assembly updates. If any updates are
>   necessary, they are performed now.
>
> The Visual Studio Tools for Office
>   runtime loads the assembly into the
>   application domain.
>
> The Visual Studio Tools for Office
>   runtime calls the Startup event
>   handler in your customization
>   assembly. For more information, see
>   Visual Studio Tools for Office Project
>   Events.

In my test project's Excel workbook I have two custom properties:

_AssemblyName, value = *
 _AssemblyLocation, value = {533b2c13-a125-418a-bfff-9546b0762807}

I suppose these are the properties which direct the VSTO runtime to my assembly.

Answer (score 6):

This is all done in the Registry, you should be able to find the key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel` or your equivelant application. I've more experience with COM Addins which are registered somewhere else in the Registry as well. This key should have a LoadBehaviour item under it which is used to determine how the application is loaded (2 is load manually, 3 is load automatically on startup).

Do you have a Setup Project for your VSTO? Inside there you can see the Registry key that is set, but the Setup program will/should also Register the VSTO in GAC (though don't take my word for it as I'm a bit shakey with VSTO as I said).

Hope this helps, I shall try and find some more information for you.

Edit
You should try reading the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386298.aspx which will give you an explanation of what the addin is. It's really just a wrapper around a COM host which is loaded from the Registry and the VSTO talks to that using some Interoparability code.

Also useful are http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23cw517s.aspx (Getting Started with Visual Studio Tools for Office, don't knock it because it says Getting Started in, there's a lot of useful info in there) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy7c6z9k.aspx (Which is linked from the first and is an overview of VSTO Addins).

Comment: I had a look under the reg key and there is nothnig there for my VSTO .Net project (there is aN 'Addins' sub dir with 2 other addins).  I don't have a setup project for my VSTO yet.

Comment: It might be under HKEY_CURRENT_USER